# Why is my ListView not scrollable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Please see code below.

I have a Fragment that inflates a layout with a single ListView "lstv" into a LinearLayout container "llytFragmentContainer" in code. The problem I'm having is that the ListView won't scroll. I know it probably has something to do with how the layout is setup.

Code to inflate layout in Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
}
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lstv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Activity Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <ProgressBar 
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="88"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="12"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtCounter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/llytFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="67">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnEnd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:text="End Tour" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How much content do you have in your listview?

Comment: Yep and try to pass the android:height to match_parent (for the ListView)

Comment: I have enough content where the listview is being cutoff by the button  "btnEnd" below the llytFragmentContainer. I've also tried to make the listview match_parent as well but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out what was wrong. Apparently, in the code, I did a listview.setEnable(false) to prevent users from checking the boxes by clicking. This also prevented the whole listview from being able to be dragged.